# Accidentally Wiped Root Partition - System Still Running

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, filesystem, dd

**Alright, this is one of those times when I am are saying... Breathe deep, don't panic.**

**What happened?**

As a usual part of leisurely tinkering with my system, I was trying write a 24.5 MB img file to my USB drive for a BIOS update. The normal command would be:

`dd if=bios.img of=/dev/sdX bs=1M`

Done that a hundred times. No problem.

Now you know **the** problem when you're mentally tired and your command turns out like this:

`dd if=bios.img of=/dev/sda bs=1M`

So it replied: `dd: failed to open ‘/dev/sda’: Permission denied`

And without thinking twice, you did:

`sudo dd if=bios.img of=/dev/sda bs=1M`

One should look happy when terminal replied this:

```
23+0 records in
23+0 records out
24117248 bytes (24 MB) copied, 0.0138706 s, 1.7 GB/s
```

But what a horror two seconds later when realizing it's your **sda**.

**What's the current status?**

The system is still up. It seems that there is a cache of the partition that Linux is reading. The original partition contained `efi`, `swap`, and `/`. I'm not sure now of their original sizes and order. The *current* partition shows only 22.98 MiB of `fat16` to be mounted on `/boot/efi`, while the rest of my SSD drive is unallocated.

So, this is one of those times when one should say... Breathe deep, don't panic, and **do not** reboot (yet).

**Any help? Pleeeaaaase? ;-) Thanks.**

Comment: 16.04 is not released so we do not support it yet. You are working from memory (as we all do) but you can not re-create your system from memory. It is gone and you need to re-install.

Comment: That's bad! As the above comment reads, you need to reinstall. (Sorry I hit close for a wrong reason by mistake)

Comment: The partition table may be still loaded in kernel... try dumping it with `tail /sys/block/sda/sda?/{size,start}`. If that works, recreate the table to match. It should work - the kernel will retain a copy of the table as long as the partition is still mounted.

Comment: Also see [How to read the in-memory (kernel) partition table of /dev/sda?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43922/how-to-read-the-in-memory-kernel-partition-table-of-dev-sda#43929)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been four days, and accepting the comments from the original question, I took the opportunity to do a **fresh install** of the system. (And that's why it's good for your home directory to be in a different disk...)

On the other hand, I think I accidentally (not again...) found the tool(s) that *could* have been used that time. "Could" was highlighted since of course, I was not able to try this. For those that can try these later (we hope not on your working system), maybe you can confirm if these really work:

1. `testdisk` from the `universe` repo. Their [official website](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) says: "It was primarily designed to help recover **lost partitions** and/or make non-booting disks bootable again when these symptoms are caused by faulty software: certain types of viruses or **human error (such as accidentally deleting a Partition Table)**. Partition table recovery using TestDisk is really easy."

There you go, automated.

2. `gpart` from the official repos. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gpart) says, "It is also good at finding and listing the types, locations, and sizes of **inadvertently-deleted partitions**, both primary and logical. It gives you **the information you need to manually re-create them** (using fdisk, cfdisk, sfdisk, etc.). The guessed partition table can also be written to a file or (if you firmly believe the guessed table is entirely correct) **directly to a disk device**."

Well, **learning is a great thing**. ;-)

---

PS

To install: `sudo apt install testdisk gpart`